# deativate doubles

Tags: modeling, faces

this is my third day with trying to learn how to model on blender and every time i get a new problem . I am trying to model this face with this tutorial , i had a problem with doubles yesterday , today i am having the same problem , even if i click the verticle and press W remove doubles , when i press E to extrude , it shows doubles again. Why doubles activates automatelly? is there any way to deactivate it ? this is realy annoying is always preventing me to go further with the tutorials, yesterday i had to close and open again and start all over the same project because i got stuck . i am following this tutorial here > https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86JiuZpbi_w , the part where i am stuck is at 5:57. this "double" thing is killing me

[image]

[image]
And i needed to undo this because its wrong. but i did undo so many times after i did this, that when i press CTRL Z nothing happens :S pfff i didnt want to start from zero again , it has been realy hard to reach to this point, watched so many tutorials so far and only this one was helping me but i got stuck again

Comment: Doubles aren't a feature you activate, you are creating them, either by mistake or out of carelessness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing extrusion <kbd>e</kbd> and grabbing <kbd>g</kbd>. 
While extrusion generates new geometry, grabbing and rotation just displaces or rotates existing geometry.

The portion of the video you mention uses grabbing <kbd>g</kbd> and rotating <kbd>r</kbd>, thus creating no new geometry.

To delete vertices you don't want, you can just press <kbd>x</kbd> or undo. Please keep in mind, that there is an object mode undo and an edit mode undo.

Remove doubles only works when vertices are in the same place (share x,y,z coordinates) otherwise you can only use <kbd>x</kbd>.

PS:

You probably never need to start from scratch, your mesh can be cleaned up quite easily.

Modelling a human head can be very challenging, I would suggest you put this on hold and do another tutorial on modeling in the meantime. I can recommend [Andrew prices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yi87Dap_WOc) for example.

Comment: Thank you so much, you were right i did it wrong and wasnt able to realise he just moved >.< thanks for the keys tip too and this video is absolutely for me